# How do I change the style?

Tags: python, docx

I've made a function and want to change the font of my title.

How can I do that?

```
def frontpage(title, student, klas, teacher, date):
    title = document.add_heading(title, 0)
    title.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.CENTER
    info = document.add_paragraph("\n" * 34 + "Naam: " + student + "\n" + "Docent: " + teacher + "\n" + 
    "Datum: " + date + "\n" + "klas: " + klas)
    info.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.RIGHT
    title.style = document.styles['Title']
    style = document.styles['Title']
    font = style.font
    font.name = 'Georgia'
    font.size = Pt(33)
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Be professional. "PLZ HALP!" isn't funny, and it isn't cute. Try to communicate properly.

Comment: Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/354577)